# How can I copy a file which gets deleted instantly

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a script, this script creates a dump in `/path/of/directory` and deletes it instantly. I want to copy that dump before it gets deleted.

I tried;

```bash
dump=$(ls -a | grep -E "^[0-9]+$")
cp $dump fulldump
```

But I only got a half of the script, not the full one.

Comment: You could probably create an eBPF program that would hook the unlink syscall and prevent the file from being deleted (assuming that you have root).

Comment: You can use inotify (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134615/using-inotify-to-monitor-access-to-a-file) to see when the file gets saved to, and then suspend or freeze the other process, (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2107/how-to-suspend-and-resume-processes) - copy the file, and then unfreeze the other process.

Comment: This question is nonsensical. Edit the script so it doesn't delete the file.

Comment: attention answerers: the file in question is actually a named pipe, according to a comment by OP.

Comment: Result of the comments: I recommend to open this as a new question, but with the following info stated in the question: a) The file in question is actually a named pipe, and b) The script in question is a third-party script that is not allowed to be edited. A fitting title might be "How to sniff and dump traffic in a named pipe without changing the script that sets up and uses the pipe". (Prepare for answers like "it's impossible", but maaybe someone knows a trick or two more than me.)

Comment: Could you recover the deleted file to a safe location? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files

Comment: This question is one big [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You've concealed the actual issue (how to tap into a named pipe, I think?) behind a made up problem (how to copy a file which gets deleted instantly). The question you've asked was answered yet you're not even a bit closer to solving your original problem.

Comment: @gronostaj The actual question [has been posted](https://askubuntu.com/q/1428335/491330). You've described the real problem quite well ("how to tap into a named pipe"); would you mind editing that question to be clearer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use chattr to prevent file deletion (while allowing file creation and modification), and other handy permissions

For directory:

```
sudo chattr -R +a /TEMP/
```

or if just the (existing) file:

```
sudo chattr +a /TEMP/youCantDeleteMe.txt
```

To revert permissions use `-a` in place of `+a`

```
$ mkdir Documents/TEMP && cd $_
$ echo can edit > youCantDeleteMe.txt 

$ sudo chattr -R +a ../TEMP/

$ echo after plusA on file>> youCantDeleteMe.txt 
$ cat youCantDeleteMe.txt 
can edit
after plusA on file

$ sudo rm youCantDeleteMe.txt 
rm: cannot remove 'youCantDeleteMe.txt': Operation not permitted

$ ls -lA
-rw-rw-r-- 1 v v   25 Sep  5 05:59 youCantDeleteMe.txt
$ echo . > youCantDeleteMe.txt 
bash: youCantDeleteMe.txt: Operation not permitted

$ touch somebody
$ ls -lA
-rw-rw-r-- 1 v v  0 Sep  5 06:04 somebody
-rw-rw-r-- 1 v v 25 Sep  5 05:59 youCantDeleteMe.txt

$ sudo rm somebody 
rm: cannot remove 'somebody': Operation not permitted

$ sudo chattr +a ./undel.txt
chattr: No such file or directory while trying to stat ./undel.txt
```

And to later remove the file

```
$ sudo chattr -R -a ../TEMP/
$ ls -lA
drwxrwxr-x 2 v v 4096 Sep  5 06:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 v v 4096 Sep  5 05:57 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 v v    0 Sep  5 06:04 somebody
-rw-rw-r-- 1 v v   25 Sep  5 05:59 youCantDeleteMe.txt

$ rm -rf ./*
$ ls -la
drwxrwxr-x 2 v v 4096 Sep  5 06:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 v v 4096 Sep  5 05:57 ..
```

Comment: It worked and didn't delete the file. But since my dump is `fifo (pipe)` file, I can't read/write/copy anything in it. Is there a way to read/write/copy?

Comment: @Erikli I recommend asking that as a separate question; it's an interesting one, but the answer is very different.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I have created it; https://askubuntu.com/q/1428335/1614432

Answer (score 19):

Congratulations, seems like you have created a *race condition*.

- Two processes are *racing* to perform operations upon the same file.
- Generally, race conditions are considered a bug for exactly the reason you encountered -- the results are unpredictable.

There are several ways to fix a race condition (semaphores, lockfiles, delays etc.) Some can involve fairly substantial coding.

However, in your specific case, you asked about a *script*. Happily, you can edit scripts. The simplest solution is to edit your script to place the dump in your preferred location.

Comment: The script isn't open source, I can't edit it.

Comment: Then you cannot fix the race condition. File a bug with the developers of that software. Or keep trying to copy the file repeatedly -- you will get a different amount of the dump each time. At some point, you might get the whole thing.

Comment: I guess I have got the whole file with `mv $dump fulldump` command but I cannot see it because it says its a pipe file.

Comment: A "pipe file" would be a *named pipe* (search for that term; great tutorials are out there). That's vital information that needs to be in your Question above, it changes the possible answers entirely: Accessing the data might be as simple as `cat < $dump`

Comment: Adding to the comment by @user535733: It also changes the chances of getting the file contents (without stealing that data from the script!) to zero: It isn't a file, it's a named pipe. Which can be read from and written to _like_ a file, but there's a crucial difference: The data is never written to disk and everything can only be read _once_. So if OP manages to read (partial) data from that named pipe, this data is then lost to the pipe consumer in the script!

Comment: @Erikli A script implies readable plain text, not a binary executable.  If that's true, can you copy it, change the copy, and change the system to use your copy instead of the original?  That might be as simple as renaming the original (as a backup - don't delete it) and giving your version that same name in the same location instead.  (now the same code runs *your* version, even if it's hard-coded)

Answer (score 15):

The `strace` utility is commonly used to show the system calls made by a process, but it can also intercept them.

Try:

```
strace -f -e inject=unlink,unlinkat:retval=0 /the/script script-args...
```

Then every time the process or its children invokes the `unlink` or `unlinkat` system calls (which are the normal ways to delete a file), `strace` will intercept it and cause it to return 0, indicating success, but without actually doing anything.

There will be a lot of output tracing all the system calls.  You can add `-e trace=unlink,unlinkat` to display those calls only, or `-o logfile` to send the whole output to a file (possibly `/dev/null`).  Make sure these arguments go before `/the/script` on the command line.

Note this will prevent the script from deleting *any* files at all; hopefully that's okay.  There's a `-P` option to `strace` that is supposed to restrict the tracing to calls that access a given file, but I couldn't get it to work correctly in a simple test.

Other variants are also possible: for instance, you can make the `unlink`/`unlinkat` system calls fail with an error code, or have them send SIGSTOP to the process so you can poke around before continuing it.  See the strace man page for the details on all its capabilities.

Comment: Wow!  Great information.  If I had read the `man` page for `strace` closely, I still probably would not have realized how useful that could be.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the speed with which the dump is opened and then written, you may be able to create a *hard* link to it while it is being written. This hardlink will ensure that the data space does not get deallocated when the file is deleted using its original name. E.g.:

```
your-script &
ln /path/of/directory/dumpfile /some/other/path/on/the/same/filesystem
wait   #  wait until your-script exits
do-something-with /some/other/path/on/the/same/filesystem
```